# Question to my code difference in int and long

Tags: java, int

heyo 
as im learning new basics I've found out that int has a limit of 2^32 -1
so I wondered if I can increase that obviously with a unsigned int or long

i tried the following

```
class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i;
        int a=0;

        for (i=1; i>0; i++) {
            a++;
        }
        System.out.println("Done, a=" +a);
    }
}
```

I've noticed that
changing long a=0 does not change the output but why?

changing i to long does change the output

in my understanding the value of i remains 0 so why does it hit the limit?

is there a way to improve my method of finding the limit?

Comment: If the value of `i` remained 0, the `for`-loop in Java would be broken and useless.

Comment: ok so if I change ' i ' to long could the printout be 2^64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `a` is our long, our program will stop for-looping well before the MAXVALUE of a `long` is reached. **So the value of `a` will be 2147483647.**

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i;
    long a = 0;

    for(i = 1; i > 0; i++) {
      // This will stop incrementing when we reach the MAXVALUE
      // of an int (i), which is 2147483647
    }

    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```

If `i` is our long, our program will attempt to for-loop (increment) *after* the MAXVALUE of `a` (an integer) is reached - **so our program will hang and nothing will be printed.**

```
class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long i;
    int a = 0;

    for(i = 1; i > 0; i++) {
      // This will try to increment **a** beyond the max
      // value of an int
    }

    System.out.println(a);
  }
}
```